# SSL CA name mismatch

Tags: java, ssl

I a new to this ssl handshaking but I am having a linux server when i am curling a https end point I am getting the response(ssl verification is done) however when i am connecting via java it fails with the following error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <hostname>
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:649)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:573)
```

i am using java version 8

Comment: Are you talking about not-accepting your tomcat server certificate on clients because of the certificate Subject or DNS name are differ from FQDN or DNS name of your tomcat host? If yes - then you need to either edit your tomcat hostname to be equal to the one in the certificate or re-generate the certificate to contain the tomcat host name. You cannot edit the name of the server it the certificate. 

Maybe the difference can be aligned? I.e. one has just a hostname and the second - FQDN?

Comment: ok may be didn't phrase the correctly. the situation that in linux server when i am curling a https end point I am getting the response(ssl verification is done) however when i am connecting via java it fails with the following error

 ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <hostname>
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(HttpsClient.java:649)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:573)

Comment: It seems you have created a self-signed certificate and in the process put in the command as is i.e. without replacing the <hostname>, essentially <hostname> is a placeholder in the command which should be replaced with the actual hostname, could be localhost or if hosted using DNS like a publically accessible site like stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

When you access your HTTPS server from curl - it also performs server identity check. Java HTTPS client does similar check. The hostname in the URL of HTTPS server must be identical to HTTPS server's certificate CN RDN of the Subject attribute or DNS name of SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension.

I found some info [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/https-hostname-wrong-during-hr-feed-ssl).

Example for the URL https://mycompany.com

Good certificate: CN=mycompany.com or SAN DNS=mycompany.com

Bad certificate: CN=aaa.bbb.mycompany.com

Comment: curl most certainly does check server name by default, although it can be disabled (with other cert checks in commandline, selectively in libcurl in most cases) -- and the _details_ of this check may depend on the underlying stack, which might matter in this case since the formatting of the Java message suggests something weird in the certificate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, I just checked, curl does server identity check by default. I ran curl with https URL of some site, checked that this site uses HTTPS server certificate with FQDN in DNS name field of SAN. Then ran curl with the same URL replaced hostname with IP and got an error of server identity check. When I specified "-k" option for the last command - curl passed. I will fix my reply above. 

Rahul Awasthi maybe you can provide more data so we can dig in. You can replace all the hostnames with dummy

Comment: Is this a bad certificate if the URL is https://api.mycompany.com and CN=api.mycompany.com ??